# template-specializaiton for a derived std::atomic<T>-class

Tags: c++

I needed an atomic that has a copy-constructor because I have a vector of objects which include an atomic. The synch-state of the atomic isn't needed to be copied of course, but the contents. I didn't really need to copy objects but I have a `vector` which is resized from zero to N and `::resize` relies on the copy-constructor naturally since it is not only built to resize vom zero. `emplace_back` wouldn't help also because it also conditionally resizes the vector and thereby calls the copy-constructor.

[EDIT]:

The "specialization" for integer-types would be this:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename T2 = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
struct xatomic : public std::atomic<T>
{
    xatomic() = default;
    xatomic( xatomic const &xa );

    using std::atomic<T>::operator =;
    using std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free;
    using std::atomic<T>::store;
    using std::atomic<T>::load;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator T;
    using std::atomic<T>::exchange;
    using std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_weak;
    using std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_strong;
    using std::atomic<T>::fetch_add;
    using std::atomic<T>::fetch_sub;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator ++;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator --;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator +=;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator -=;
    using std::atomic<T>::fetch_and;
    using std::atomic<T>::fetch_or;
    using std::atomic<T>::fetch_xor;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator &=;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator |=;
    using std::atomic<T>::operator ^=;
};

 template<typename T, typename T2>
inline
xatomic<T, T2>::xatomic( xatomic const &xa )
{
    *this = (T)xa;
}
```

But how can I have a non-intger "specialization"?

Comment: *"relies on the copy-constructor"*. move constructor should be enough.

Comment: Vector resize will use the move constructor if it is noexcept.

Comment: Moving/copying an atomic makes no sense, at least not when it's in use as a synchronization tool, as doing so requires synchronization. You could make as many of them as needed before starting the threads (incidentally that doesn't require copying), but moving them while already in use won't work.

Comment: I resize vom zero to N and this operation uses a move- / copy-constructor, whatever is available. This happens before any synchronization happens on the atomics and the vector is never resized so that the atomics would be moved or copied. So this all makes perfectly sense what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of back-porting copy semantics to `atomic` types (which as can be seen is not easy, if even possible), an alternative solution is to avoid copying them.

From the comments it seems you only need it at startup/initialization time, and because `vector::resize()` requires it. So we can avoid the issue in various ways.
For example:

1. Count how many `atomic`s you need, and then create them all at once.

   ```
   int n = 100;
   std::vector<std::atomic<int>> vec(n); // does not involve copying
   ```

   This works because `vector<T>(size_t n)`, requires `T` only to be [DefaultConstructible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/vector#cons-4).
2. If the `atomic` is part of a larger structure, create a custom copy constructor that properly initializes all `atomic` members instead of copying them.
3. Use a data structure that does not move elements on resizing. For example, `std::list` or `std::deque`.

---

An additional note regarding `vector<atomic<int>>`: storing data of unrelated threads too close together can cause [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads). So a data structure like `vector<atomic<int>>` might not be a good idea from a performance perspective.